# In jQuery, is it possible to target the child of a child in the selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a fairly new hand at jQuery, and there's something that I ran into today and I'm not sure how to handle.  Basically I want to target the child of a child of an element, by knowing the class of the first element.  As an example, here's a simple click listener that looks for any a in .my-class:

```
$('.my-class > a').click(function(){
   //Do something here.
})
```

But lets say for example we wanted to select the child of a child, or what in my mind would look like this:

```
    $('.my-class > div > a').click(function(){
      //Do something else here.
    })
```

Assuming we don't can't have the id or class of the div or a, what's the best way to target it with the selector?

Thanks for reading.

edit: closed the functions

Comment: Did you at least try it before asking, as it will work just fine ?

Comment: I did, but I must have made a mistake somewhere in the code.  I'll try it again- thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Well, you didn't close any of those functions properly ?

Comment: Please give OP a chance. I think these kind of questions are actually ok when you're totally new here - even if it is rather easy to find in  documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods in the jQuery API that might help you: [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

Both take a selector. `children` will run on all immediate children of the element upon which you call the method. `find`, on the other hand, will run through all of its direct and indirect children.

You could, for example, use a piece of code like this:

```
var div = $(".myClass");
var a = div.children("a");
```

Or:

```
var div = $(".myClass");
var a = div.find("a");
```

And then you may do as you wish with the anchors you will fetch by using these. I also like this approach because you have each set of elements in separate variables, which is useful if you are going to do more things with those elements further on your code.

Do read the documentation for them, and try it out with your console. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

It is a lot easier to do this way:

`$('#element').find('#child').find('#grandchild')`

Obviously you could replace `#child` with `div` for example.

Comment: Why would that be easier, it's seems more like unneccessary as ID's are unique ?

Comment: Because in jQuery it seems easier using jQuery methods rather than loads of CSS selectors, it is in my opinion easier to see what is going on.

Comment: My point being that it's a poor example, as you should never use `find` with an ID, that's a sure sign that you're doing something wrong, and `find` is not even remotely the same as the direct descendant selector.

Comment: @Zak: really? How confusing do you find CSS to read? And, as noted, the results of the differing approaches won't necessarily be the same.